# Highlighting certain HTML elements using Qt web viewer

Tags: qt

I'm working on Qt. I have an application in which a web page appears. Is there any way that on the website comes out, you can put a filter or image that can highlight, for example, only the buttons that appear on the website? 
Thank you very much and greetings.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. What does "web page appears", "on the website comes out", "put a filter or image", "on the website"(which one?) mean? If you do not improve your question soon it might get downvoted for missing clarity.

Comment: sorry, I do not speak English. 
I have a window in which there is a website. 
I need to highlight the images that appear on the website and they are no images appear darker. 

I do not know if you understand me. 
greetings.

Comment: start from QtCreator examples (Ctrl+1), enter 'webkit' in 'Search in Examples...', enjoy either `Fancy Browser` or `Simple Selector`

Comment: I have not succeeded. 
I do not know how to highlight the buttons on the website and leave the other darker.